# What is difeerence between those two tabs and why doughnut chart won't rerender itself from not hardcoded dataset?

Tags: vue-chartjs

I have a very strange problem with Doughnut chart from vue-chartjs.. when I'm getting my response from rest api and converting it to datasets which looks almost the same like hard coded datasets the chart won't rerender itself. It seems like data from resp is not identical but I tried to give him both datasets in 2 separate attempts. So when I give him my hardcoded dataset then doughnut rerender but In case of rest api datasets converted to normal arrays it won't.. I printed everything in console so please check if those 2 datasets are not the same, in my opinion they are the same...

Hardcoded dataset:
[image: Hardcoded]

Data set from api after conversion:

[image]

I don't really know what is going wrong but yesterday I tired to resolve this for 7 hours looking for a lot of problem with re rendering this chart and finally it rerenders but only when I use hard coded dataset. Please help me if You have some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I tried to assign data to existing empty datasets when it should be done by creating new one with assigned data from response.